# Reconciling small aggregates and Invariants on parent/child relationships

Tags: domain-driven-design

First, my understanding/asuumptions of aggregates.
* Aggregates are the only domain objects that can be accessed directly.  If an aggregate has children, they have to be accessed through the aggregate.
* Aggregates can have references to other aggregates by their id.  Meaning I could load Aggregate A through its repository, get an id reference to Aggregate B and the load B via the repository.
* Large aggregates can cause concurrency issues if the root aggregate and a child entity are updated independently at the same time.

For my example, I have a membership system based on chapters.  Chapters have members.  Users should be able to make changes to the different members at the same time, so that leads me to make Chapter and Member each their own aggregates.

BUT we have a rules that say

- A) a member must belong to a chapter
- B) a chapter cannot have two members with the same name and birth
  date.

A feels like I should have code like this

```
 var member = chapter.EnrollMember(memberInfo);
```

And that code should throw an error if the chapter already has a member that matches the parameters passed in for B.  But if the chapter aggregate only has id references to the other members, how should it get those members?

- Pass in the member repository?
- Move the Member name check out of the Chapter aggregate and into a Domain Service?

NOTE: This is a hypothetical situation.  I'm looking to see how this situation could be modeled, not whether it should be modeled this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set validation for large sets is usually not practical to handle in the domain. If you are using a relational DB you could potentially protect this invariant using a unique constraint.

Another approach could be to rely on eventual consistency, where you detect broken rules after they were broken and issue compensating actions (automated or manual). In order to determine if eventual consistency is an option you'd have to evaluate the cost of breaking this rule for the business and that's why modeling hypothetical scenarios is not so helpful. In a real world scenario you'd ask why it so important that members can't have the same name and birth date (entirely possible in the real world)? How much would this cost to the business if that rule would be broken? How often is it likely to happen if commands are validated on the UI before being sent (e.g. uniqueness check on the UI), etc.

If somehow the membership uniqueness policy is extremely important, must be strongly consistent, but is too complex to be modeled as a unique constraint then you could model an AR that only maintains the minimal state to protect the invariant, while all other member details are handled on a separate AR. For instance, the member's `name`, `birthdate` and `status` could be modeled on a `ChapterMember` entity that lives within `Chapter` while a `ChapterMemberProfile` AR could hold other details that are not subject to set validation.

```
//Enroll
var memberProfile = chapter.enrollMember(name, birthdate, avatarFilePath);

transaction {
    save(memberProfile);
    save(chapter);
}

//Change avatar for a given chapter
var memberProfile = find(chapterId, name, birthdate);
memberProfile.changeAvatar(avatarFilePath);

save(memberProfile);

//Disenroll (you could also modify memberProfile in the same transaction for this specific use case -- if needed)
chapter.disenrollMember(name, birthdate);

save(chapter);
```

Comment: Will you follow-up with more question details? Not sure what your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: What did you end up doing? ;)